# Non-static create-new-from method?

Tags: java, static-methods

I sometimes write classes which can be converted to- and from- something else, and I'm used to writing it as a non-static convert-to method and a static convert-from method, for example:

```
class A {
    B toB() {...}
    static A fromB(B b) {...}
}
```

or

```
class B {
    void save(File f) {...}
    static B load(File f) {...}
}
```

I used to think it's a good and simple approach, but lately the static-ness of the conversion-from method has been annoying me, for instance if I want to define an interface for types that can be converted to- and from- `B`:

```
interface ConvertableToAndFromB {
    B toB();
    // ?
}
```

So, is there an elegant way of doing that without having the conversion-from as static, other than migrating to Smalltalk?

#### EDIT

To clarify, I realize I *can* add a non-static method in the interface, e.g.:

```
interface ConvertableToAndFromB {
    B toB();
    void fromB(B b);
}
```

or, if I want to allow immutable types (thanks Stripling):

```
interface ConvertableToAndFromB<T implements ConvertibleToAndFromB<T>> {
    B toB();
    T fromB(B b);
}
```

But that will require me to create a new `A` before I can even invoke this, as in:

```
A a = new A();
a.fromB(b);
```

or (for immutable):

```
A a = new A();
a = a.fromB(b);
```

which is what I'm trying to avoid (but will do with no other solution). I just hope there's a nicer way.

Comment: You may like to keep `fromB(..)` or `load(...)` type of methods in a separate `Factory` class, which again can implement its own interface.

Comment: Why can't you just remove the static keyword from your `from` methods?

Comment: @GarrettHall you mean first creating an instance via `new` and then calling `from` on it? I don't consider this very elegant, especially when dealing with immutable classes, but I agree it *is* a valid solution.

Comment: I don't like the idea of "convert from" as an interface method. How would you call it on the destination object if  you just have the source object? If you want to say "create from" use a constructor that takes the source object as a parameter. If you need polimorphism use converter objects.

Comment: @gpeche so, you mean similar to the "Converter" shown below by Stripling, and it will internally use that constructor?

Comment: @Oak no, it is more an either-or: you implement a constructor or you implement a converter object. If you have a look at Java code out there you will find that most nontrivial libraries/frameworks use some converter facility as it is the most flexible solution in Java. But for simple scenarios, doing `ClassA a = new ClassA(b);` is just fine.

Comment: Why does `fromB` need to be in an `interface`?  What type would you return?

Comment: @gpeche right, thanks :) I guess using a constructor is a pretty decent and simple approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, a fromB method would be implemented as a copy constructor.  E.g.

```
public class A
{
  public A(B b)
  {
    this.someValue = b.someOtherVariable;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not help you create an interface to abstract said functionality.  Normally, a separate factory could be used, and this factory implement an interface, but this would still not allow you to get around being able to implement the method in your object in a non-static way while avoiding unnecessary instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to make your interface recursively generic. I believe the syntax is like this:

```
interface ConvertibleToAndFromB<T implements ConvertibleToAndFromB<T>>{
    B toB();
    T fromB(B b);
}

class A implements ConvertibleToAndFromB<A> {
    B toB() {...}
    A fromB(B b);
}
```

Making things more strongly typed like this has obvious advantages. However, it does mean that you have to be somewhat aware of the actual type that you want when you call `fromB`. There are advantages and disadvantages to this approach.

As a side note, making `A` responsible for generating objects of type `A` or `B` violates the *Single Responsibility Principle*, and I would generally prefer to have a separate Converter class or interface to perform these actions.

```
Converter<A, B> converter = converterFactory.get<A, B>(A.class, B.class);
B b = converter.from(a);
```

Comment: But it still requires me to convert `fromB` to be non-static, so I need to first create an instance before invoking it. That's the primary thing I'm trying to avoid (see my comment above), though I agree it *will* work.

Comment: @Oak: Please see my update. The problem you're facing arises because you're trying to use a class as a static factory class for producing instances of itself. Interfaces cannot define static methods, because that would break the whole inheritance model. So you should use a separate class for creating instances.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, I'll do it this way:

```
interface ConvertableToA {
    A toA() {...}
}


interface ConvertableFromA {
    Object fromA(A a) {...}
}


class MyConvertableClass implements ConvertableToA, ConvertableFromA {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This could in some scenarios even be extended so that `ConvertableFromA` is generic, taking the type you want to convert *to* as a generic type argument. That way, you'd get (compile-time) type safety on the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

creating a utility helper class might be better because if you think about it, conversation has nothing to do with the object/instance.

for example, when you convert an array to list, you don't do arr.asList(), rather, you use Arrays.asList(arr)